# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'corsFilter'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have instantiated the corsFilter bean but it is throwing me error like "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'corsFilter'" and my code is:

```
package com.ashwin.springsecurityangular;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityAngularApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityAngularApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source=new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config=new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter((CorsConfigurationSource) source);

    }
}
```

I am going these steps looking the tutorial but at the last line in the video tutor has used this code:

```
return new CorsFilter(source);
```

But when I did the same step it says me :
the constructor corsfilter(urlbasedcorsconfigurationsource) is undefined

My pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aswhin</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurityAngular</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringSecurityAngular</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Angular</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace the exception generates?

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: its ok i solved the problem my import was wrong .

Comment: maybe delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
```

with

```
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
```